# how to synchronize 2 threads(on different servers) inserting and selecting data.

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle

how would one prevent 2 threads inserting and selecting the same data? So for example T1 hasnt inserted the data yet and T2 checks to see if the data is there. T2 and T1 could insert the same data.

Comment: What about just adding a unique constraint in the database table you're inserting to?

Comment: This is what database transactions are for.  Having a unique constraint would be good too.

Comment: I already have composite primary key on the table. Any other ideas besides unique constraints?

Comment: If you first session doesn't commit session any other sessions can't see uncommited data no matter you have constraints or smt else.

Answer (score 0):

You should look a thing aroud the data locking into you data base.

You'll arrive at somthing like ; when T1 or T2 is about to insert some data, before inserting, it will lock the table so let the other know there is a work in progress.

And like [Mureinik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2422776/mureinik) says, add a constraint on your table.

Comment: data locking on database level?

Comment: wouldnt that make things really slow? @Zorglube

Comment: Slow... Perhaps, but the question is : "what is your need ?" after answering that you'll be able to choose your solution; lock, unicity, de normalize bdd, read/write engine with FiFo request list, other.